# CSS question about a submenu

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a page with a navigation bar up top and, below it, a content box featuring its own menu on the side. The idea is that you could select an option from the navigation bar and then the content box would show up with its menu.

I've almost got it working. The problem is that the side menu's options don't work. They're associated with the correct links (you can see this when hovering), but clicking on them does nothing. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/uM3JL/

Also, it might help to look through the code for "ai1" or "bi1", as these are the options that won't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A *right* fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/y4H6C/

Comment: I'm a little confused by the request.  What is supposed to happen when you click on them?  I can read jQuery code and I see what's happening, but I don't see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JCOC611 I'm sorry, I don't understand. Have you made some change to the original?

Comment: @jerebear I'd like e.g. a click on ai1 (Option A, Item 1) to pull up the text "You've selected Option A, Item 1!"

Comment: @Dave2: I just made a new fiddle with the HTML code on the HTML box, the CSS code on the CSS box and the JS code on the JS box...instead of having all the code smashed on one box...

Comment: clicking on them does nothing because you don't have anything in your code that is even attempting to do anything when you click on them....

Comment: @jlbruno: Here's the code that I thought would do something: `<li><a href="#ai1">Item 1</a></li>`. I thought clicking on "Item 1" would bring up the "ai1" div, just as clicking on "Option A" brings up the "optiona" div. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Dave, here is a fiddle that adds some script to do what you're looking to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/y4H6C/1/